# Not an enclosing class Error (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

In the following piece of code I am getting an error when attempting to pass DisplayWishesActivity.this, in my custom adapter. DisplayWishesActivity is another activity, which hasn't been modified yet. (please refer to the code for the error line)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import data.DatabaseHandler;
import model.MyWish;


public class WishDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
    private ArrayList<MyWish> wishList;
    private WishAdapter wishAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wish_detail);

        wishList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_id);

        refreshData();
    }

    private void refreshData(){
        wishList.clear();

        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        ArrayList<MyWish> wishesFromDB = databaseHandler.getWishes();

        for(MyWish wish : wishesFromDB){
            String title = wish.getTitle();
            String date = wish.getRecordDate();
            String content = wish.getContent();

            MyWish myWish = new MyWish();

            myWish.setTitle(title);
            myWish.setContent(content);
            myWish.setRecordDate(date);

            wishList.add(myWish);

        }
        databaseHandler.close();

        //setup adapter

//*******ERROR********* -->>"DisplayWishesActivity is not an enclosing class"            

        wishAdapter = new WishAdapter(DisplayWishesActivity.this, R.layout.wish_row, wishList);  
    }


    public class WishAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyWish>{          //Private Class
        Activity activity;
        int layoutResource;
        MyWish wish;
        ArrayList<MyWish> mData = new ArrayList<>();

        public WishAdapter(Activity act, int resource, ArrayList<MyWish> data) {
            super(act, resource, data);

            activity = act;
            layoutResource = resource;
            mData = data;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public MyWish getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getPosition(MyWish item) {
            return super.getPosition(item);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return super.getItemId(position);
        }


        //This method is the heart of our custom adapter class, as this is the place where our custom ListView is created

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(row == null || row.getTag() == null){              // i.e. the our list view (row) is currently empty
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.mTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.wish_title_in_list_id);
                holder.mDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.date_in_list_id);

                row.setTag(holder);
            }

            else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();         //prevents the system from doing all the work again, but instead recycles the views
            }

            holder.myWish = getItem(position);

            holder.mTitle.setText(holder.myWish.getTitle());
            holder.mDate.setText(holder.myWish.getRecordDate());

            return row;
        }
    }


    class ViewHolder{              //helps in recycling the listView, rather than instantiating it every time
        MyWish myWish;
        TextView mTitle;                         
        TextView mId;
        TextView mContent;
        TextView mDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what makes you do this but this is wrong. The syntax:

```
ClassName.this
```

Can only be used in the `ClassName` class. In your case, when you try to use

```
DisplayWishesActivity.this
```

it gives an error because you are not in the `DisplayWishesActivity` class. You need an instance of the `DisplayWishesActivity` class to call the `WishAdapter` class's constructor. Try to create an instance of `DisplayWishesActivity` class or just find an instance of that class to replace

```
DisplayWishesActivity.this
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks very much!! Just realized that the entire code which wrote in WishDetailActivity was supposed to be written in the DisplayWishesActivity class (since that is my class corresponding to listView layout). Embarassing..